# Deleting the Core Data store from iCloud

Tags: core-data, ios7, icloud

I'm trying to use [iCloudCoreDataStack](https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack) for syncing my app's Core Data store over multiple iOS7 devices. This works, meaning I can work offline and add data on the real device and this will shows up later in the simulator after going online.

However, I am unable to delete all data stored by my app in iCloud. Even if I delete the app from the simulator and my device, going into the settings app (*Storage and Backup* -> *Manage Storage*) and deleting my app's data there, reappears later if I reinstall the app again. I've waited several hours after deleting.

What's the proper way of manually deleting everything an app has stored in iCloud? Can the user do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator removeUbiquitousContentAndPersistentStoreAtURL:options:error: API

If the app has been deleted then use the Settings app to managed iCloud storage

```
Settings->iCloud->Storage&Backup->Manage Storage->AppName.
```

[image]

Comment: The user himself can't do that?

Comment: Yes he can if you program a button or action to call that API.  Check out this link for some examples of deleting stuff in iCloud if the use turns the iCloud option off in the app settings bundle. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/

Comment: What if the user already uninstalled the app? There must be a way for the user to free used iCloud space?!

Comment: Settings->iCloud->Storage&Backup->Manage Storage->AppName now offers the user the chance to delete all the apps iCloud data regardless of whether the app is installed or not. Useful for developing/debugging :)